# Scala Plugin missing in IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.1

Tags: scala, plugins, intellij-idea

I am trying to install Scala plugin for IntelliJ IDEA, but it doesn't show up in the plugin list.

I am using version 11.1.1

[image]

---

Btw, it did show up a few months back on my friend's pc, he uses version 10.5.2
Here's the snapshot ..

[image]

Has anything changed now for installing the plugin ? I tried Google'ing but no success.

Any solution / workaround ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Browse repositories:

[image: browse]

Install the plug-in:

[image: install]